# How to retrieve format_spec from a string?

Tags: python

In order to retrieve different fields in a text created using string.format, I want to parse line by line a text and check the format_spec of each line.

```
Foo       Test    Description of the block                                      42          
toto      -         8 0.000000E+00 2.152000E+03
titi      -         2 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00
```

In this example, for each line, I want to retrieve the format_spec.
For the first line, the result is:

```
'{0:<10}{1:<8}{2:<60}{3:>4}'.format('Foo', 'Test', 'Description of the block', '42')
```

The purpose of this manipulation is to be able to filter the lines according to their format_spec in order to know the fields contained in each line.

I tried to retrieve it using the method below:

```
def retrieve_format(str):
    previous = 0
    length=[]
    for i, c in enumerate(str[1:], 1):
        if c==' ' and str[i-1]!=' ':
            length.append(i-previous)
            previous = i
    length.append(len(str)-previous)
    return length
```

However, this method returns the distance between each space which does not correspond to the formatting of the line.

So would anyone have an idea in order to get the actual formatting of the line?

Comment: Well, `[m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'^|$|(?<=  )\w', string)]` gives you the boundaries between fields, assuming that they're separated by at least two spaces.  Taking differences between elements in that list gives you the field widths.  But you're certainly never going to recover the fact that '42' was right-justified in a 4-character field from just looking at that one line.  (EDIT: there are two spaces after the equals sign in that regex)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally managed to retrieve the desired fields using the regex that you indicated to me.